# Add controller reference/pointer to c++ singleton class

Tags: c++, ios, pointers, reference, member

I have a singleton class called playbackhelper to which I want to add a member that is a reference to a viewcontroller. But I don't think I can make the member a reference because I want to be able to change which controller I'm linking to and I don't think that's possible with a reference.

This is my controller:

```
@interface InstrumentGridViewController : UIViewController {

}
-(void) someMethod;
@end
```

And this is my singleton class on which I want a member that is some kind of pointer to the controller.

```
class PlaybackHelper{

private:

    // Singleton methods
    PlaybackHelper();
    PlaybackHelper(PlaybackHelper const&);
    void operator=(PlaybackHelper const&);

public:

    static PlaybackHelper &getInstance();

    // ((((some InstrumentGridViewController member here))))
    InstrumentGridViewController controllerMember;
}
```

So my question is: how can I link those with each other/how do I make a member that points to the controller and how should it be initialized?

**EDIT:** Basically I want to be able to call the controller methods from the singleton class, like this:

```
[PlaybackHelper::getInstance().controllerMember someMethod];
```

But I don't know how to set my singleton up to make this possible. The way it is set up in the example right now `controllerMember` would be a copy of the controller object which is not what I want.

Comment: Before using a singleton I suggest you read a slightly biased view on them :-) https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid but the article makes some very good points IMHO

Comment: You can use objects in C++ just fine (and they operate as expected under ARC).  However, I don't understand your question.  Please rephrase the part starting with "So my question is:"

Comment: I updated my question. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Yes but won't I need to initialize that somehow inside the PlaybackHelper constructor?

Comment: "I want a member that is some kind of pointer to the controller"... well? `InstrumentGridViewController* p_controllerMember_;`. You'd typically provide a public `set(InstrumentGridViewController*)` method, and let the caller worry about the controller's lifetime.  In the constructor, you can also take a pointer to record, or just put a `NULL` in there and document that the `set()` method above should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debates about singleton use aside, if you are using ARC, you can easily use ObjC objects inside C++ classes, and memory management is taken care of.

If you want to make it an accessor...

```
class PlaybackHelper{
private:
    // ... other stuff...
    InstrumentGridViewController *_instrumentGridViewController;

public:
    InstrumentGridViewController *controllerMember() {
        return _instrumentGridViewController;
    }
};


[PlaybackHelper::getInstance().controllerMember() someMethod];
```

If you just want to make it a public member...

```
class PlaybackHelper{
public:
    InstrumentGridViewController *controllerMember;
};


[PlaybackHelper::getInstance().controllerMember someMethod];
```

ObjC objects are recognized to have non-trivial ctor/dtor, and the compiler will automatically take care of the ARC stuff.

LLVM + ARC + C++ makes it easy to mix ObjC objects with C++.  In fact, you can do this without worrying a bit...

```
std::vector<UIView*> listOfViews;
```

All the memory management is magically arranged by the compiler.

Comment: I tried this, and even changed my header file to `.mm` but it doesn't compile. Do I need some sort of statement on top to let the compiler know there's an Obj-C class in the code? I thought something like that was necessary in the other direction

Comment: Nope.  It just works.  Since you didn't show what you are compiling, nor the error you are getting, I can't offer much except to confirm that it does, indeed, work.

Comment: As soon as I add `InstrumentGridViewController *controllerMember;
 ` as a (public) member I get all these errors when I try to run: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7qYNC.png

Comment: Are you including that header file in regular C++ source files?  If you have a header that mixes both C++ and ObjC you need to only use it in .mm files -- actually there is a way to get it to work without doing that but it is somewhat advanced -- the simple solution is to only use C++ and ObjC in .mm modules.

Comment: That seems to have been the problem, I changed the header file extension t `.mm` instead of the source file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I misspoke then, because I don't want you to change your header files to .mm, that's not it.  You can leave your header files as .h, but you should only include them in .mm source files if the header contains both ObjC and C++.

Comment: Yea, I got that. What I wanted to say is that changing the header files to .mm instead of the source files was causing the errors.